# Impossible to connect with open ssl key with username@hostname on debian server

Tags: linux, ssl, hostname, debian-buster

when i try to connect to with username@hostname and not username@ip my command line return a error:

`OpenSSH\\ssh.exe: Could not resolve hostname ns335234: H\364te inconnu.`

I use this tutorial to do it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-debian-10

I try many things now it is 5 hour on and i don t find the solution if good dev can help me. :)

My version of linux: debian buster 10.

Thank' s by advance for any help.

Have a nice day. ;)

Comment: `OpenSSH\\ssh.exe` Are you really on linux?  Wha is the line you are executing?

Comment: yes my server is linux but i connect to my server with a windows computer the line i execute is ssh username@hostname when i do with ssh username@ip it work but with no ssl I had a open ssl key on my server debian for username@hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a new tutoriel i use visual studio with remote dektop (with that you can see your file on the server debian and edit directly on visual studio code it is
amazing !!! :) )Install  visual studio code +remote desktop module on the client windows.

------windows client-------

1. Create the private and public key on terminal of visual studio code with `ssh-keygen` add a passs phrase for more security to your private key

------Linux Server---------

2. Copy the public key create on windows client on linux server in `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

3)Do if you are not root ad sudo before  `chmod -r 700 /home/<user>/.ssh`

4)Do a `chmod -r 600 /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys`

-----Windows client-----

5)Click on connect to host on VSC add ssh username@ip op hostname

6)In the config file of .ssh you have know `Host:alias name HostName:your hostname User:username`  add it `IdentityFile:Path of you private key`

NOW try to connect it work amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

insert a line:

[ip of target machine] ns335234

in your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

Comment: It work but it use my password of username@ip normaly it need to use my passphrase from my create ssl it just bypass the problem. ty for help

Comment: you need to disable password authentication in your openssl config of the machine you are connecting to. use -vv for more verbose output of what happens in the background.

Comment: Maybe i have something to change in my hosts debian it configure like that 127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.1.1 debian.example.com 127.0.1.1 ns335234.ipMYIP ns335234

Comment: another thing is to check the known hosts of your debian, and delete and add again the public key, connecting with hostname

Comment: i do it and same result denied

Comment: sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password to PermitRootLogin yes 
PasswordAuthentication no to PasswordAuthentication yes
then, restart ssh service:

sudo service ssh restart

Comment: when i compare my public key in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  with authorized_key it is not the same is it normal ? i think it had in authorized key from etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pup in authorised key and when i try to connect in my server to windows it had this key too now itis 16 hour no sleep my brain is off i need to sleep i come back tomorow thank s a lot for your help i try what you say tomorow

Comment: well just delete the line in authorised keys and add the correct one

Comment: already do it but when i connect on windows it takes the key from  etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pup automticly and not the key from authorized who i have change manuelly i think with hostkey and redirection the good file in sshd_config is may be the solution what do you think ?

Comment: your key should be in C:\Users\your_username\.ssh
the .pub should be copied to the authorised_keys on your debian

Comment: do you add it like this: ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host ?

Comment: i use just ssh-copy-id user@host not with the i and and the direction file

Comment: it do the same likei use ssh-copy-id user@host

Comment: maybe i need to copy too my public key in /etc/ssh/rsakey ? because too connect it take the key from etc/ssh/ecsa key and on debug i search the key here not in the file /home/user/.ssh/authorizedkey

Answer (score 0):

Re,

I find the solution it is just i write authorize_key and normally it is authorize_keys

1 day lost but know i have a ssh-keygen config to windows client to linux server with visual studio code and a remote desktop

@Armando Ballaci @ KamilCuk thank you for all your help :)

Have a nice day